# Pandas DataFrame Groupby two columns and get different relation in same keys insert list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have this table :

```
  Head  Relation    Tail 
0   9       1          0 
1   10      1         11  
2   9       0         23 
3   10      1         61 
4   9       0         12
5   10      0         66
6   10      0         61
```

I have to create a dictionary with Head key and values ​​equal to the relations but not repeated and for each value of the relations I have to insert the corresponding tail.

example:

```
{9 : {1: [10], 0:[23,12]}, 10 : {1:[11,61], 0:[66,61]}}
```

I don't really know how to do it. Is there someone who can help me?

[image: Result with nan.]

**Second Example Input:**

```
    Head    Relation    Tail  
  0 207       1         269  
  1 207       1          61  
  2 207       0          62  
  3 208       1          269 
  4 290       0          269
```

**the output:**

```
{207: {0: [62], 1: [269,61]}, 208: {0: nan, 1: [269]},
 290: {0: [269], 1: nan}}
```

I would like to remove the nans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Head', columns='Relation', values='Tail', aggfunc=list)
   .to_dict('index')
)
```

Or, the other way around:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Relation', columns='Head', values='Tail', aggfunc=list)
   .to_dict()
)
```

output:

```
{9: {0: [23, 12], 1: [0]}, 10: {0: [66, 61], 1: [11, 61]}}
```

###### post-processing the output to remove NaNs:

```
d = (df.pivot_table(columns='Head', index='Relation', values='Tail', aggfunc=list)
     .to_dict()
     )

d2 = {k: {k2:v2 for k2,v2 in v.items() if pd.isna(v2) is not True}
      for k,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Hi, just a question about pivot tables. is it possible to have `filter`  in pivots like `columns` and `values`?

Comment: @mozway Thank you so much! I was wrong to enter the attributes in the pivot_table! I prefer the first solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @Greencolor what do you mean by `filter`? Can you provide an example (or open a new question)?

Comment: @mozway 
if, on the other hand, some tails do not have the relation, how can I remove this from the dictionary?

Comment: @Vallinox can you update the question with an example?

Comment: Speaking from excel pivot table capabilities, you have an opportunity have a filter which creates a drop done list.  https://imgur.com/a/w5qYkK4 like this

Comment: @mozway Yes I posted the example photo [2]

Comment: please post **text**, not images, a small example of input/output ;)

Comment: @Greencolor you mean aggregation function? I don't use Excel so I'm not sure what it does here ;) Anyway, might be better suited for its own question

Comment: @mozway this is an example.                                                                                                                    {8: {0: [222], 1: nan}, 18: {0: [60], 1: nan}, 19: {0: [128], 1: nan}, 21: {0: [54], 1: nan}, 22: {0: [18, 69, 17], 1: [16]}, 23: {0: [18], 1: nan}, 28: {0: nan, 1: [167]}}

Comment: @Vallinox I meant of the **input** (sorry), like you nicely did in the initial question

Comment: You can't add large amount of code in comments, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70790482/edit) function

Comment: @mozway I edit now.

Comment: @mozway I tried to inserT dropna=True, but nothing.
 data.pivot_table(index='Head', columns='Relation', values='Tail', aggfunc=list, dropna=False).to_dict('index')

Comment: @Vallinox I see, you can't really do anything at the dataframe level, you have to process the dictionary. See update